# REST api: best practices in case of no content

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status-code-204

I'm pretty familiar with rest apis, but today I was asked this:
"what if a resource exists but it's content have been blocked for some reason?"

example:
try to retrieve `users/18` but user with id 18 has been banned/blocked/whatever.

I think the best answer would be to return 204, but how to also inform the client of the reason for the resource is not available to you?

is there a best practice for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the best answer would be to return 204, but how to also inform the client of the reason for the resource is not available to you?

No, 204 isn't a good choice -- in particular because 204 cannot [contain a message body](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5).

I would expect either

[403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).

[404 Not Found](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)

> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of 404 (Not Found).

[451 Unavailable For Legal Reasons](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7725#section-3)

> This status code indicates that the server is denying access to the resource as a consequence of a legal demand.

Comment: thanks for your comment. can you think of a situation that doesn't fall into any of the error codes? what to do in such a case? should we try to fit all the cases into code errors or it would make sense to act differently sometimes?

Comment: You could certainly make a case for `200 OK` -- the blocked message _is_ the current representation of the resource.  You might also be able to argue for `303 See Other`.